# Android: onRequestPermissionsResult runtime multiple

Tags: android, permissions

I want get 5 permission from user

My code:

```
public void requestPerm() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 1);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 1);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 1);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 1);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 1);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("errorCheck","YES");
                startRequest();
            } else {
                Log.i("errorCheck","NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use `requestPerm()` in `MainActivity`.java with `onClickListener`

After click user for get `requestPerm()`, before user click ALLOW or DENY, i get log twice "NO"

I want return result only on click user ALLOW or DENY

But now, on lunch `requestPerm()` return result "NO"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different requestCode for each permission.

```
public void requestPerm() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 100);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 101);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 102);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 103);
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permissions = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, 104);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 100: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("errorCheck","YES");
                startRequest();
            } else {
                Log.i("errorCheck","NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And create switch cases accordingly in onRequestPermissionsResult method.

Use this only if you want to perform different operation on different on permission result.

And if you want perform same operation for all permission and all permission are required then you following code to handle permissions :

```
private void checkForPermission(final boolean askForPermission) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) //Check all permission here. {

            android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("We need to access your phone book to identify calls from unknown numbers.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (askForPermission) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Auto_MissedCall_HandlingActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST); //Ask for all permission at time here with single result code.
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();


        } else {

            /* All Permission Allow Do your code here*/
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST:

                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   /*All Permission Allow and Do Your Code here*/

                } else {

                    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("Oops permission denied");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                }

                return;
        }

    }
```

And Do Not forget to add all permissions in Menifest.xml

Menifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Android Marshmallow also supports handling several permissions at a single time on app start up or button click. This feature allow us to request different permission at a single time so there is no need to ask again and again permission on each time when your application wants to access some data.

Use below code at Launcher Activity of your code :

Menifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Your Activity looks like this :

```
  import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(checkPermission()){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Permissions Granted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {

                    requestPermission();
                }

            }
        });
    }


    private void requestPermission() {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]
                {
                        CAMERA,
                        READ_CONTACTS,
                        READ_PHONE_STATE
                }, RequestPermissionCode);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case RequestPermissionCode:

                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean CameraPermission = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean ReadContactsPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean ReadPhoneStatePermission = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (CameraPermission && ReadContactsPermission && ReadPhoneStatePermission) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermission() {

        int FirstPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA);
        int SecondPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_CONTACTS);
        int ThirdPermissionResult = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_PHONE_STATE);

        return FirstPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                SecondPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ThirdPermissionResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

}
```